# How to use begin() tag in python 3.5?

Tags: python

How to use begin() tag in python 3.5? I mean I'm trying to make a text-based RPG, but I don't know to use the begin()  tag because if you run it, it will spam the Py Shell. It'll keep on spewing "You ran into a Zombie! The Zombie has 100 HP, Do you attack?" and those things.

```
import time
import random
import sys
import time
global gold
global HP
gold = 0
print ('Welcome to Battle Deongeons')
myName = input('Whats your name?')
print ('Ok ' + myName + ' you need to kill monsters...')
choice = input("Do you want to play? Y/N")
if choice == "Y":
    print('Lets start the Battle')
    begin()
def begin ():   
    global gold
    global HP
    print('Remember you can type "moves" to be reminded of the moves you have...')
    print('To attack, type "Attack!".')
    rewards=random.randint(1,3)
    mob=random.randint(1,3)
    if mob==1:
        print('You ran into a Zombie!')
        print('The Zombie has 100 HP!')
        print('Do you attack?')
        if choice == 'Attack!':

            gold=gold+rewards
    if mob==2:
        print('You ran into a Headless Horseman!')
        print('The Headless Horseman has 125 HP!')
        print('Do you attack?')
        if choice == 'Attack!':

            gold=gold+rewards
    if mob==3:
        print('You ran into a Demon!')
        print('The Demon has 130 HP!')
        print('Do you attack?')
        if choice == 'Attack!':

            gold=gold+rewards
    if gold > 100:
        print ('You have killed all the monsters!')
        play = input('Do you want to play again? Y/N?')
        if choice == 'Y':
            print('Then restart th program, silly!')
        if choice == 'N':
            print ('Okay, battle later')
            sys.exit(0)
if choice == "N":
    print ('Okay, battle later')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Hi Justin. You've bitten off more than you can chew. Start out with a much simpler program. Make it ask your age and then print something if its < 20 and something else if its >= 20. Gradually make it more complicated. After  each change, test it. And look up some tutorials on the internet. Programming is fun, but you learn it step by step. By the way 'tags' are HTML (or grafitty). In Python begin () is called a function.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to help you without writing the whole program for you, which users on this site are unlikely to do.

However, I will offer you some advice that will hopefully get you in the right direction:

1. Make sure that you define `begin()` (which we refer to as a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), not a tag) before you actually call it. This means before you do:

   ```
   if choice == "Y":
       print('Lets start the Battle')
       begin()
   ```

   you need to do:

   ```
   def begin ():
       ...
   ```

   so that your program knows what `begin()` means.
2. You assign `choice` only once, to `Y` or `N`, but you do the follwoing check inside of `begin()`:

   ```
   if choice == 'Attack!':
       ...
   ```

   So choice will never be `'Attack!'`, since if the game actually runs, we know that `choice == "Y"` and will until the script is run again.

   When checking whether the player wants to attack, you are going to need to get the player's `input` again:

   ```
   if input('Do you attack?') == 'Attack!':
       ...
   ```

   or better yet:

   ```
   if input('Do you attack? y/n?').lower() == 'y':
       ...
   ```

   This way the player's response does not have to be the very specific string `'Attack!'`, and also, the test is case-insensitive, so if the player's response is `'Y'` or `'y'`, the test will pass. You correctly get new input from the user at the end of the `begin()` function with `play = input('Do you want to play again? Y/N?')`, but then you check the value of `choice` not the value of `play`.
3. As for the program "spewing" out text, this will happen every time `print()` runs.